# Do I need a nametag for my converted Zombie Villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently trapped a Zombie Villager, and then immediately cured him, using the old weakness-splash-potion-and-golden-apple "one-two" trick. I stayed nearby until he turned back into a regular villager, then blocked him off (for safe keeping) until I needed him for future use.

I went off, and did my thing (only 34 blocks away - yes I counted) and when I came back, he was gone! I thought he was secure, so I don't think any mobs could get to him, but could he have despawned, due to his origin as a Zombie Villager? Do I need to name my Zombie Villager? Or is it possible that a mob (perhaps a baby zombie) killed him?

[image: Zombie Villager Trap]

As you can see, the only block that is not a solid block, is the fence gate (which I made sure was closed). This is in Vanilla Minecraft, in a single-player map.

Comment: I have no authority behind this, but hunch tells me you don't need name tags, just "a village"  for the villager to be in - structure(s) corresponding to village houses (door plus a piece of roof)..

Comment: Only safe place for villager is one that has maximally half-block hole. All others can get eaten by baby zombie. But also bad stuff happens by itself.

Comment: *"Whether in a village or not, a villager is never prone to despawning."* - [Minecraft Wiki - Villager](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Villager#Illagers). Sounds like it might've been attacked/killed, unless you have any mods which mess with the spawning/despawning mechanics.

Comment: If the gate is closed baby zombies can't attack them, also if it was daytime, baby zombies (and other hostile mobs) would have burned to death.

Comment: @sensiwoo there is a newbie in the newer versions of the game called "husks". These are zombies that spawn in the desert, and don't burn in the day time. There is also baby husks.

Comment: could you provide a world download, or similar, of the place you kept the villager? And have you tried again to cure, or just keep a villager in the box to see if the problem happens again? you mentioned that its Vanilla MC, what version are you using?

Comment: @Ben that is true, but the gate was still closed so nothing could go in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out that the way I had built my little "shelter" was not exactly the best.

The way I had built it, I had neglected to add the corners of the "shelter"

[image: Corners]

It was because of this, the zombies were able to gain access to the villager. This is due to the fact that when tracking the player, mobs tend to slide along the sides of blocks, causing the hitbox to rub up against the edge of the block. In this case, it can allow it to poke out the corners, between blocks, allowing Zombies to identify it, and kill it.

Answer (score 7):

Villagers, in Vanilla Minecraft, do not normally despawn, whether or not you have a nametag for them (per a number of entries on the Minecraft forums/wiki).

There are a number of ways that a villager may disappear (baby zombie attack through a 1 block hole, glitching themselves to death, or other bugs in the game, for example, getting too close to a door and being attacked through a wall).

Heck, I watched one jump on top of a 1 block high cactus and die because he was too stupid to jump down, but they aren't supposed to despawn once present (even if converted from a Zombie Villager).

Comment: He said "Zombie Villagers", not "Villagers."

Comment: @Tassu The question says "until he turned back into a regular villager". Converted zombie villagers *are* normal villagers.

Answer (score -1):

It was either a baby zombie that killed him, or a glitch occurred and it despawned him.

Comment: Not sure why the answer got a down vote. :P

Comment: Probably because it doesn't provide much detail.